# Apply CSS only for number in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

If I have JSX like

```html
<div>Hello there are 123 oranges</div>
```

Here's how text is set.

```js
const Component = ({text}) => {
  return(
    <div>{text}</div>
  )
}
```

I wanna make `123` red color. However, the text inside div is dynamic, so I can't insert span by hardcoding. Hopefully CSS can detect numeric but I couldn't find one by googling.

Are there any good and concise solutions?

Comment: No, it would have to be a mechanism of the dynamic text.  There isn't a numeric selector that will only change the color of numbers.  Show how the text is getting set dynamically.

Comment: @zero298 I added react to show how the text is set dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It 's possible with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you need regex to match the numeric part from your dynamic string and then generate the updated string with a style wrapped around that numeric part.

```
 const yourText = yourText.replace(/\d+/, m => `<span style="color: red">${m}</span>` );
```

then pass this to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourText}}></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought about using dangerouslySetInnerHTML but I want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try with regex

```
text.replaceAll(/(\d+)/g,'<span className="num">$1</span>')
```

`String.prototype.replaceAll` is an ES10 method.